# How to download file via FTP java code

Tags: java, ftp, client, inputstream

Need to download file from server using FTP, without using existing libraries and 3rd parity solutions. I manage to connect and login to server, post type mode of transfere (ASCII) and passiv mode so I get port number and opened new ServerSocket(port). But when I call RETR fileName, my program blocks on InputStream.readLine() (on reading server port, means server is not responding ) Is there something before calling RETR comand that I forgot to do?

```
//PASV
outputStream.println("pasv");    

//227 Entering Passive Mode(a1,a2,a3,a4,p1,p2)
String response = inputStream.readLine();   

// port = p1*256 + p2
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);

//RETR fileName 
outputStream.println("retr "+ fileName);

//server no answer
String reply = inputStream.readLine()
```

Comment: is this homework, cause i can't imagine another reason why you wouldn't want to use existing libraries?

Comment: Review the difference between passive and active mode.

Comment: Yes, its homework. Unfortunately existing libraries are not allowed.

Comment: @parsifal Can u please be more specific? I chose passive mode because dont know hoe to chose port num by myself

Comment: I'll assume that you have some book that gives a complete description of the FTP protocol. You need to go through your code and compare what you're doing to what the specification says you should be doing. I'll give you a hint: a passive-mode client doesn't establish a `ServerSocket`. However, that's not your only problem. You need to *read and understand* the specification before trying to implement it.

Comment: Thank you, it was very helpfull. I manage to download file. Do you know where I can check for concurrent FTP transfer, cause Im trying now to download few files in parallel but while one thread downloadnig, other blocks on its own socket(with new port)?

Answer (score 0):

FTP PASV command will not open a socket on the client side, the IP and port is returned to the client FROM the server basically telling the client "Ok connect to me on this IP and port". Kindly review RFC 959 for implementation details. FTP client implementation in JAVA is not a trivial process.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void download(String remoteFile) {


    FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();

    try {
        ftpClient.connect(server, 22);
        ftpClient.login(ftpUser, ftpPassword);
        ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

        // APPROACH #1: using retrieveFile(String, OutputStream)
        File downloadFile1 = new File("D:/ftpdosyam.txt");
        OutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream(downloadFile1));
        boolean success = ftpClient.retrieveFile(remoteFile, outputStream);
        outputStream.close();

        if (success) {
            System.out.println("File #1 has been downloaded successfully.");
        }
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```